# Div height resize with jQuery mCustomScrollbars not correct on the first load

Tags: php, jquery, css, html

I have a problem when resizing the height of a `div`.

I set the height of the `div` with JavaScript, but it only works when I refresh the page (F5).

How can I get it to work without a refresh?

The code is below:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function (){  

    $("#wr1").hide();
    $("#header").hide();

    var aa = $("#wr1").height();
    var bb = aa-80;
    var cc = $("#detail-about1").width();

    $("#detail-about1").css('height',bb);
    $("#wr-close").css('width',cc);

    $(".nav li a").click(function (){
            $("#wr1").slideDown();
            $("#header").slideDown(); 
            $("#footer").slideUp();                                           
            mCustomScrollbars();
        });
});

</script>
```

Comment: you have written the script that work when the page get loaded.. that's why

Comment: You really need to describe this in more detail, since your English is hard to understand.  No offense, just describe the problem and conditions a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

Your resize code is only being fired on page load. Look at JQuery's resize() method so that you can have your code called whenever the window is resized.

Edit:
Looking at your updated code block, maybe you mean to call the resize from your click function? Either way, move the resize code into a function that can be called as needed.

Answer (score 0):

whenever you want to call that click work . Trigger it.. Call this line whereever you want it to work

```
$(".nav li a").trigger('click');
```